# Remote debugging error with eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using Galileo CDT on mac os x 10.5.7. I want to remotelly debug a c++ application on a linux machine. I found this guide:

http://www.embedded-linux.co.uk/tutorial/eclipse-rse

But when it comes to the step

"Install Remote System Explorer", when I go to "available software", I only get error messages like "No repository found at http::/downlo" and so.

So please,
1- Is there any other way to install this package or to solve this issue?
2- Is there any other better/different guide to remotely debug c++ application with eclipse(galileo)?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only get error messages like "No repository found at http::/downlo" and so.

What is the exact error message?
Do not forget Eclipse has its own HTTP proxy settings. Please check them out. (Preferences / General / Network Connections)

[alt text http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/whatsNew/images/system-proxy-settings.png](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/whatsNew/images/system-proxy-settings.png)

If your browser is using a proxy then you need to configure Eclipse to use one too.

If your proxy has a cache and you are using eclipse `<` 3.4.2, you may get some further problems with that until release 3.4.2 which will include a fix for [bug 249990](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=249990):